# How to set attribs in GWT?

Tags: java, gwt, coding-style, width

I'm not getting any effect out of `DOM.setElementAttribute`, am I doing something wrong?

```
class MyListBox extends com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.ListBox {
  ....
  protected void setHoverAutoWidth() {
    addDomHandler(new MouseOverHandler() {
      public void onMouseOver(MouseOverEvent event) {
        DOM.setElementAttribute(getElement(), "width", "auto");
      }
    }, MouseOverEvent.getType());
    addDomHandler(new BlurHandler(){
      public void onBlur(BlurEvent event) {
        DOM.setElementAttribute(getElement(), "width", "100px");
      }
    }, BlurEvent.getType());
  }
}
```

(I know there are less hacky ways to change the width than to set the style attribute directly, but I don't care about css right now.)

**Edit:** Oops, just realized that width does not change the style width, just adds a width attribute to the  tag (which explains why nothing happens). Any suggestions on how to modify the style are still welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that will attempt to set the `width` attribute of the element (which may not exist for the type of element you are working on), *NOT* the CSS `width` property.

You're probably looking for [`setStyleAttribute`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/index.html?overview-summary.html#setStyleAttribute(com.google.gwt.user.client.Element,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 1):

Use [DOM.setStyleAttribute](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/user/client/DOM.html#setStyleAttribute(com.google.gwt.user.client.Element,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Answer (score 1):

In later versions of GWT you can use `getElement().getStyle().setWidth(100, Unit.PX)`, which gives you a bit of extra compile-time correctness over the String-based methods in the DOM class. Use `getElement().getStyle().clearWidth()` to set the width back to `auto`.